# Error in Name Space after migrating to JSF 2.2

Tags: jsf, namespaces, jsf-2.2

I am facing below issue, after I migrated to JSF2.2

```
 com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437) [:2.2.0]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214) [:2.2.0]
```

I have made changes as per specifications as well I went through below url :
http://jsfcorner.blogspot.in

and My changes are like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

and including passthrough as well

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:pt="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

Comment: i think you may mixing jars or configurations. have you changed you project facelets to 2.2. ?

Comment: Yes, I did a mvn clean as well and try to build and deploye the application in maven way excluding eclipse

Comment: works fine for me. I think a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) is needed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The way how the new `xmlns.jcp.org` XML namespaces are been handled is broken in the first Mojarra releases 2.2.0 and 2.2.1. Among others, they overlooked to properly register the new JSF 2.2 components/tags/attributes/handlers. It has been fixed in Mojarra 2.2.2 as per [issue 2900](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2900) (note: issue ticket describes different problem symptom, but under the covers, it's essentially the same cause).

So, upgrading to at least Mojarra 2.2.2 should fix your problem. It's [currently](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/) already at 2.2.5.