# The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined

Tags: eclipse, jsf-2, jboss, jboss7.x

i am trying to use JSF 2.2.2 on Jboss 7.1.1.Final
i followed the solution 1 in this link:
http://www.mastertheboss.com/jsf/installing-jsf-22-on-jboss-as-7
that is based on replacing the current jboss jsf libraries
and after that i changed the faces config.
but when trying to run the application i am getting the following exception:

```
22:28:56,076 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

22:28:56,080 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/motivosity]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:273) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named passThroughAttribute from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:214) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    ... 8 more

22:28:56,087 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Error listenerStart
22:28:56,088 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-1) Context [/motivosity] startup failed due to previous errors
22:28:56,089 SEVERE [javax.faces] (MSC service thread 1-1) Application was not properly initialized at startup, could not find Factory: javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. Attempting to find backup.
22:28:56,090 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-1) Unexpected exception when attempting to tear down the Mojarra runtime: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find backup for factory javax.faces.application.ApplicationFactory. 
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder$FactoryManager.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:1135) [jsf-api-2.2.2.jar:2.2]
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:379) [jsf-api-2.2.2.jar:2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:140) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextDestroyed(ConfigureListener.java:310) [jsf-impl-2.2.2.jar:2.2.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3489) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3999) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3917) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]

22:28:56,095 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/motivosity]] (MSC service thread 1-1) Cleaning up Shiro Environment
22:28:56,099 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./motivosity: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./motivosity: JBAS018040: Failed to start context
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
```

i removed the configuration for jsf in project facets and still get same error, please advise how can i fix that.

**UPDATE:** i found out that the issue is in **eclipse deploy to jboss**, since i tried to install the application with maven and copied the war to deployments folder and launched **standalone.bat** file and the application was started successfully with no errors.

Comment: Unanswered dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331406/error-in-name-space-after-migrating-to-jsf-2-2

Comment: @BalusC any advise about the deployment issue on my last update ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to Project Properties -> Project Facets -> Java Server Faces, and set type to **Library Provided by Target Runtime**.

Answer (score 10):

I had the similar issue when we migrated our application, please make sure you have included  `jsf` jars in `scope provided` like below:

```
<jsf.version>2.2.2</jsf.version>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

change your `project facet` `(Project->Properties->Project Facets)` and make sure your `jsf` is poiting to the right set of `jar`

Do a clean build, hope this will resolve the above issue

Comment: in project facets there's only jsf version 2.1, do i have to reconfigure it to use 2.1 and add custom library that contains the new jars ? please explain the part of project facets.

Comment: can you please tell me what is exactly you did in project facets ?

Comment: ok, check your project facet if its showing 2.1, then go to your build path you will find jsf 2.1 , there make a edit and point to your new jar (Build Path-->Libraries->jsf2.1->edit>use libraries->edit)

Comment: ok here's what i did in project facets, i choose java server faces 2.1 and choose user library in further configuration and created a new library that contains the two new jars for jsf 2.2 but when clicking ok, i get the following error in eclipse: `Invalid classpath publish/export dependency jsf-api-2.2.2.jar. The project contains another dependency with the same archive name`

Comment: Project Facet->Java Server Faces->jsf 2.1 (will be clicked already)->in right hand side you will find manage library (it will open new window ) click on jsf2.1 ->remove already present jar, then add jars

Comment: well i don't have  jsf 2.1 library on my build path because i was used to disable library configuration and it was working fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36808/discussion-between-mahmoud-saleh-and-jayaram-pradhan)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. I solved it by removing this dependency in my pom.xml.

```
<dependency>
 <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
 <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
 <version>2.2.0-m15</version>
</dependency>
```

This dependency is only needed when deploying on Tomcat, not on Jboss.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You'd have to your project libraries and remove the Mojarra 2.2.x implementation JAR

Answer (score 0):

In NetBeans, you'll have to uncheck "Package" option against JSF library in the Project Properties window.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem, I solved change this Java Server Faces, go to right click to your proyect and go to Properties->Project Facets->Java Server Faces and change

 from: "Jsf 2.2 (Mojarra 2.2.0)" 

 to "Jsf 2.0 (Mojarra 2.0.3-FCS)"