# Error in name space after migrating from glassfish 4 to wildfly 8.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces, namespaces, wildfly, mojarra

I am migrating from glassfish 4 to wildfly 8.1.

Before project had been migrated from jsf 2.0 to jsf 2.2 and everything worked well on glassfish 4

This exception comes when I try to deploy an application to wildfly 8.1:

```
INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Initializing Mojarra 2.2.6-jbossorg-4 20140501-1134 for context ''
22:35:02,685 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (MSC service thread 1-4) Critical error during deployment: : com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]

22:35:02,686 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:219)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.start(UndertowDeploymentService.java:72)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:275)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ApplicationListeners.contextInitialized(ApplicationListeners.java:173)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.deploy(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:190)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: The tag named inputFile from namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html has a null handler-class defined
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processHandlerClass(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:422)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTags(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:378)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.processTagLibrary(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:321)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.process(FaceletTaglibConfigProcessor.java:270)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:437)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:216)
    ... 9 more
```

Project spec: JSF 2.2, WildFly 8.1, Primefaces 5

By the way Mojarra version is 2.2.6 so there is should not be issue like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17331406/error-in-name-space-after-migrating-to-jsf-2-2)

Comment: Which jsf library do you use?

Comment: JSF 2.2, I have wrote it

Comment: Can you check this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167509/jsf-implementations-and-component-libraries

Comment: Well, if say jsf library I use JSF 2.2 library and Primefaces5. If say about another Java libraries I use many of them. Main libraries are commons-fileupload, commons-io, poi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution

In case if you already migrated to JSF 2.2 remove JSF 2.2 library from project library list because Wildfly 8.1 alredy comes with JSF implementation.

Comment: GlassFish also comes with its own. This problem only occurs if the JSF impl/version differs and you didn't tell the container to use webapp-bundled JSF impl instead of its own JSF impl.

Comment: In general, any of the Java EE libraries should not be bundled with the WAR file. They are always provided in the underlying Application Server. Let us know how your migration experience goes.

Comment: Thanks. everything works fine, but now I cannot login using wirlfly security domain http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25719659/cannot-login-using-wildfly-security-domain