# Cannot login using Wildfly security domain

Tags: jsf, authentication, wildfly-8, securitydomain

I am migrating from glassfish 4 to wildfly 8.1

Problem is in login using security domain of Wilfly. I cannot find solution for hours.

here is my standalone-full.xml security domain configuration:

```
<security-domain name="aisRealm" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/jdbc/ais"/>
                            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select password from users where email='subsoil_user'"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select ug.group_name, 'Roles' from user_in_group uig, users u, user_group ug where uig.user_id = u.id and uig.user_group_id = ug.id and u.email = 'subsoil_user'"/>
                            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
                            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="BASE64"/>
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RoleMapping" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="file:${jboss.server.config.dir}/ais.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="replaceRole" value="false"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
```

alse here I have made default security domain

```
<default-security-domain value="aisRealm"/>
```

here is my configurations in web.xml:

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <realm-name>aisRealm</realm-name>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login_error.xhtml</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

here is configurations in ais.properties:

```
ADMIN=ADMIN
SUBSOIL_USER=SUBSOIL_USER
SUPPLIER=SUPPLIER
```

and jboss-web.xml configuration:

```
<security-domain>aisRealm</security-domain>
```

login.xhtml:

```
<h:form>  
                <h:panelGrid columns="3" columnClasses="login, pass, login_btn">                    
                    <h:inputText id="loginName" value="#{userBean.loginName}" />                      
                    <h:inputSecret id="password" value="#{userBean.password}" />  
                    <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="#{dictionary['login']}" action="#{userBean.login}" ajax="false"/>                                                              
                    <ui:remove>
                        <p:commandButton id="loginButton" value="#{dictionary['login']}" action="#{userBean.login}" process="@this"/>  
                    </ui:remove>                    
                </h:panelGrid>  
            </h:form>
```

UserBean Login function:

```
public void login() {
        FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest();

        try {
            request.login(loginName, password);

        } catch (ServletException e) {
            Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
            try {
                facesContext.getExternalContext().redirect(facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + "/error?statusCode=login_failed");
                return;
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }   }
```

it gives me the following exception:

```
SEVERE [kz.ais.user.UserBean] (default task-32) null: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010031: Login failed
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.login(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:426) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at kz.ais.user.UserBean.login(UserBean.java:66) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:275) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304) [javax.el-3.0.0.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-impl-2.1.2.Final.jar:2014-01-09 09:23]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198) [jsf-impl-2.2.6-jbossorg-4.jar:]
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646) [jboss-jsf-api_2.2_spec-2.2.6.jar:2.2.6]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:70) [primefaces-5.0.jar:5.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:113) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:25) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:240) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:227) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:73) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:146) [undertow-servlet-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:177) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:727) [undertow-core-1.0.15.Final.jar:1.0.15.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_20]
```

Answer (score 1):

I have figured out the issue. That was my bad, I didnt check correctness of EclipseLink work. After a little investigation I found that

```
<exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
```

in my persistence.xml do not work, I mean all classes excluded anyway. I have added all entity classes manually in persistence.xml as follows

```
<class>kz.ais.entities.Users</class>
```

After that EclipseLink is working fine. So above configuration for security domain correct and it works with my project also.

Good luck